# Overlay on top of tbody

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a loading overlay on top of **tbody** (and only tbody). My current solution is to add tr as the last element of **tbody** and set it as **position: absolute**, and setting tbody as **position: relative**.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

tbody {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>Label</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data</td></tr>
    <tr class="overlay">
      <td>My overlay</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Expected behavior is that an overlay covers **tbody**, but not **thead**. Also this overlay is supposed to contain some content (f.e. refresh button) so covering every **td** is not an option.

My solution works perfectly in Firefox, but not webkit. Webkit somehow ignores **position: relative** on **tbody** tag and thus the overlay covers the whole **table** and more.

---

RESOLVED 
*I have managed to make this approach work by adding **display: table** on **tbody***

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS calc should help with this. [Support is fairly good](https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) for the property too.

You just need to balance the calc with the top property.

So your CSS would become:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 25px);
  height: calc(100% - 25px);
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7);
}
```

Here's a working example:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 25px);
  height: calc(100% - 25px);
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><td>Label</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data</td></tr>
    <tr class="overlay">
      <td>My overlay</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Updated answer using CSS Calc.

Comment: You got an error: tr without td. Valid html breaks supposed view.

Comment: Unfortunately by using this approach, the whole table is coverered by overlay not only tbody.

Comment: For me it's covering most of the table, but leaving the table header visible.

Comment: @TomášOndruš I can confirm that the `thead` element remains visible with this method (in Chrome and FF Quantum)

Comment: @TomášOndruš please see my updated answer. It's using calc now.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO: **In browsers which support CSS3** `position:relative` on table elements **should work**.
As you have rightly revealed: it works only in Firefox. Not in IE, Edge and Chrome.

#### Sources:

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#valdef-position-relative

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#property-index

> Property name: `position` Applies to: all elements except `table-column-group` and `table-column`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#relative
About 'stacking context' but that is not the subject of this question

> This value (`position: relative`) creates a new stacking context when the value of z-index is not auto. Its effect on `table-*-group`, `table-row`, `table-column`, `table-cell`, and `table-caption` elements is undefined.

#### Related question:

[Bug in most browsers?: Ignoring position relative on 'tbody', 'tr' and 'td'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51843534/bug-in-most-browsers-ignoring-position-relative-on-tbody-tr-and-td)

Answer (score -1):

you have to remove the position relative on tbody and out it on table instead.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>Label</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Data</td></tr>
    <tr class="overlay">
      <td><div>My overlay</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: This is strange. The snippet you provided actually works in here, but not in my project (react based). Is there anything that can mess up calculation of the top offset or something? (there are no additional styles applied to it)

Comment: I don’t think you need any additional style. Although there might be other style in your project that overrides this style somehow. What I can suggest is that check your css carefully to see where exactly it’s being overridden

Comment: You see, this example does not behave as expected. This is because the HTML code in example is not valid. `thead tr` missing `td`. After the bug fixes, the example behaves correctly. But then it is not a solution to the problem.